# Perl <STDIN> not matching contents in an array

Tags: perl, filehandle

I have a file which consists of three names: daniel, elaine and victoria. If I search for daniel I get "you are not on the list". Could someone kindly point out where my mistake is? Thank you.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

#open file 
open(FILE, "names") or die("Unable to open file"); 

# read file into an array 
@data = <FILE>; 

# close file 
close(FILE); 

print "Enter name\n"; 
$entry = <STDIN>; 
chomp $entry; 

if (grep {$_ eq $entry} @data) 
{ 
print "You are on the list $entry"; 
} 
else 
{ 
print "Your are not on the list"; 
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to `chomp` (remove *new line character* from the end of each string) data from the file too:

```
chomp @data;

if (grep {$_ eq $entry} @data) { 
    print "You are on the list $entry"; 
} else { 
    print "Your are not on the list"; 
}
```

Comment: +1 for this. I didn't know that `chomp @array` removes the last char from all entries. I used `map{chomp;}@array` before.

Answer (score 2):

change this

```
if (grep {$_ eq $entry} @data)
```

to this

```
if (grep {$_ =~ m/^$entry\b/i} @data)
```

remove the i if you specifically want it to be case sensitive.

Comment: @Harry_Barry `victoria` and `vic` will match equally here.

Comment: @mpapec sorry my bad, fixed.